# Representing a SQL join with a merge in python (pandas) when one of the join conditions has an increment

Tags: python, sql-server, join, pandas, merge

I'm trying to transform the following SQL Server code into pandas

```
SELECT DISTINCT  alfa.machine_id, alfa.domain_name, alfa.ss2k
FROM CTE01 alfa
LEFT JOIN CTE01 beta
ON alfa.machine_id = beta.machine_id and alfa.ordering = beta.ordering +1
WHERE 
alfa.domain_name != beta.domain_name
or beta.domain_name is NULL
```

I can easily do a merge (join) on one condition:

```
aux1 = pd.merge(df, df, on='machine_id', how='left')
```

but I don't seem to find a way to merge/join on the second condition as one of the values has to be incremented by one i.e. alfa.value = beta.value + 1

Is there a way to represent that sort of condition in pandas?

I tried moving the condition as if it was in the WHERE part of the SQL clause using the following python code:

```
aux1 =  aux1[aux1['ordering_x'] == aux1['ordering_y']-1]
```

but it doesn't give me the same results.

Comment: Why not pull in a more raw df and then do all the manipulation in pandas?

Comment: To add specifically, why not connect Python to SQL Server via ODBC, pulling [select query as a pandas data frame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html). I'll leave an SQL engine tasked to do joins than pandas. Just my two cents.

Comment: AZhao, I'm trying to do everything using a "raw" df, but can't achieve the results I want.  Parfait, I don't want to rely on a SQL connection as I want to work directly with the (text) output from a Hive query

Comment: Do you mean [Apache HIVE](https://hive.apache.org/)? HiveQL supports SQL-like statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
data_1 = data.copy()
data_1['ordering'] = data['ordering']+1
df = data.merge(data_1, on=['machine_id','ordering'], suffixes=('_from', '_to'))
df = df[(df['domain_name_from']!=df['domain_name_to']) | (df['domain_name_to'].isnull())]
```